# VSCode debug test. error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, mstest

In Visual Studio Code, clicking on the "debug test" code lens link in my test project:

[image]

results in the error message:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use
because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.
```

The error message makes sense, there ARE indeed several projects to choose from but **how do I point the debugger at the correct one?**

I tried changing the .csproj file that my build task pointed to in tasks.json but it didn't have any effect. A quick google turned up the general VSCode docs for debugging but I couln't find how to configure the build task for a "debug test" event.

Comment: I know this isn't a fix, but could you just split up your projects so there isn't multiple per directory? It's almost certainly a good idea in the long run anyway.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks - certainly a valid suggestion - I do entirely agree with your 1 proj per directory in principle - unfortunately, as of today, pragmatically it's simply a no go for me (at least for now) with this solution for horrid "ugly" reasons I won't clutter the question with :-/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to setup the testing project and other referenced layers in the vscode tasks.json and launch.json

Answer (score 0):

You can specify explicitly project or solution file by path passing it to build args as last parameter.

It may be project **.csproj** or solution **.sln** file.

> MSBuild.exe [Switches] [ProjectFile]

[MSBuild cli reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

Sample tasks.json:

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "msbuild",
        "args": [
            // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/t:build",
            "solution_file.sln"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems more like you have your .vscode folder and the solution file of your project not aligning. The folder structure should look like this

```
Project Root
 |--> .vscode
      |--> launch.json
      |--> tasks.json
 |--> YourProject.sln
 |--> YourProject.cproj
 |--> ....
```

So move your .vscode folder to the root folder of your project and you won't need to manually add the solution file to the arg list, unless you have multiple solution files in the root of your project.